# How to get to home screen of Android Studio when inside a project?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, import, gradle, android-studio

This is what I am currently seeing. (inside Android Studio project)[image]

Is there a way I can get to the opening Android Studo home screen from here? By home screen, I mean [image]

I tried closing the project and starting the studio64 executable but that took me to my existing project(GradeTrackr, same one that I closed)
I tried looking this up via the all powerful search engine.  - https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+get+to+home+screen+of+andorid+studio but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way I can get to the opening Android Studo home screen from here?

Choose File > Close Project from the main menu.